# Escaping hstore contains operators in a JDBC Prepared statement

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, hstore

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1.4 with hstore and the [PostgreSQL JDBC](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/) driver (9.1-901.jdbc4).

I am trying to use the contains operators (`?`, `?&`, `?|`) in a PreparedStatement, however the `?` character is parsed as a variable placeholder. Can this character be escaped to send the correct operator in the query?

An example:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT a, b FROM table1 WHERE c ? 'foo' AND d = ?");
stmt.setInt(1, dValue);
stmt.executeQuery();
```

In this form the following example would raise an exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 2.
```

**Update:**

After investigating the query parser in the pgjdbc driver [this snippet](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/master/org/postgresql/core/v3/QueryExecutorImpl.java#L164) seems to indicate that it is not possible to escape the `?` character. The questions that remain are:

- Is there anything in the JDBC spec which allows a `?` to be escaped and be anything other than a parameter placeholder?
- Is there any better work around for this issue than just using plain Statements with variables manually inserted into the query string?

Comment: Don't know any JDBC but does `d = $1` work?

Comment: No, that's not valid syntax. Throws a syntax error at the `$1`.

Comment: Many PostgreSQL interfaces prefer numbered placeholders (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, ...), I guess JDBC isn't one of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Effectively, it looks like the java SQL parser is not hstore compliant.

But since the syntax `c ? 'foo'` is equivalent to `exist(c, 'foo')`, you can easily workaround this problem. Have a look at the following page to see what the *verbose* operators for hstore are.

[Postgres hstore documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the verbose operator down there.

Comment: It's important to note that `exist(c, 'foo')` does *not* use an index. Check a query plan with and without to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is a discussion about this issue on pgsql-hackers mailing list: http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-hackers/1325c6ys9n/alias-hstores-to-so-that-it-works-with-jdbc

For now I like most this workaround which also supports indexes:

```
CREATE FUNCTION exist_inline (hstore, text) RETURNS bool AS $$ SELECT $1 ? $2; $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query to find the function backing an operator in PostgreSQL like this. In your example:

```sql
SELECT 
  oprname, 
  oprcode || '(' || format_type(oprleft,  NULL::integer) || ', ' 
                 || format_type(oprright, NULL::integer) || ')' AS function
FROM pg_operator 
WHERE oprname LIKE '?%'
AND (SELECT oid FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'hstore') IN (oprleft, oprright);
```

This produces:

```
|oprname|function                  |
|-------|--------------------------|
|?      |exist(hstore, text)       |
|?|     |exists_any(hstore, text[])|
|?&     |exists_all(hstore, text[])|
```

[See also a related question about using JSON operators containing `?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38370973/521799). Note that the function usage may not profit from the same indexing capability when using a [GIN index on your HSTORE column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20589058/521799).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to add multiple key-value pairs using PreparedStatement then you can do:

```
PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement(
                     "insert into xyz(id, data) values(?, hstore(?, ?))");

ps.setLong(1, 23456L);
ps.setArray(2, c.createArrayOf("text", new String[]{"name", "city"}));
ps.setArray(3, c.createArrayOf("text", new String[]{"Duke", "Valley"}));
```

This will insert: `23456, 'name=>Duke, city=>Valley'`

Comment: this has nothing with the question asked