# PostgreSQL jsonb, `?` and JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, anorm, jsonb

I am using PostgreSQL 9.4 and the awesome JSONB field type.  I am trying to query against a field in a document.  The following works in the psql CLI

```sql
SELECT id FROM program WHERE document -> 'dept' ? 'CS'
```

When I try to run the same query via my Scala app, I'm getting the error below.  I'm using Play framework and Anorm, so the query looks like this

```scala
SQL(s"SELECT id FROM program WHERE document -> 'dept' ? {dept}")
.on('dept -> "CS")
....
```

> SQLException: : No value specified for parameter 5. 
>   (SimpleParameterList.java:223)

(in my actual queries there are more parameters)

I can get around this by casting my parameter to type `jsonb` and using the `@>` operator to check containment.

```
SQL(s"SELECT id FROM program WHERE document -> 'dept' @> {dept}::jsonb")
.on('dept -> "CS")
....
```

I'm not too keen on the work around.   I don't know if there are performance penalties for the cast, but it's extra typing, and non-obvious.

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Either you don't paste the code properly or you have syntax error: `SQL(s"SELECT id FROM program WHERE document -> 'dept' ? {dept} .on('dept -> "CS")` → `on` must be apply on `SQL(...)`, not be part of the statement string as it seems to be there = `SQL("...").on(...)`. Note that string interpolation there is useless.

Comment: I didn't paste the whole call to SQL because it's irrelevant to my quesion.  There is a call to `apply` after the `on`

Comment: I would have been better to paste a code which has valid syntax if you want appropriate answer.

Comment: There seems to be a fix in the latest JDBC driver that allows escaping the questionmark by doubling it: `??`. See http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CADK3HH+Fbr4+TBrpmK7pSbVkBei7pHmB99ANU_Km1HnjCEmO6w@mail.gmail.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a workaround to avoid the ? operator, you could create a [new operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/sql-createoperator.html) doing exactly the same.

This is the code of the original operator:

```
CREATE OPERATOR ?(
  PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists,
  LEFTARG = jsonb,
  RIGHTARG = text,
  RESTRICT = contsel,
  JOIN = contjoinsel);

SELECT '{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb ? 'b'; -- true
```

Use a different name, without any conflicts, like #-# and create a new one:

```
CREATE OPERATOR #-#(
  PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists,
  LEFTARG = jsonb,
  RIGHTARG = text,
  RESTRICT = contsel,
  JOIN = contjoinsel);

SELECT '{"a":1, "b":2}'::jsonb #-# 'b'; -- true
```

Use this new operator in your code and it should work.

Check pgAdmin -> pg_catalog -> Operators for all the operators that use a ? in the name.

Answer (score 5):

In JDBC (and standard SQL) the question mark is reserved as a parameter placeholder. Other uses are not allowed.

See [Does the JDBC spec prevent '?' from being used as an operator (outside of quotes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14779896/466862) and the [discussion on jdbc-spec-discuss](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2013-February/000048.html).

The current PostgreSQL JDBC driver will transform all occurrences (outside text or comments) of a question mark to a PostgreSQL specific parameter placeholder. I am not sure if the PostgreSQL JDBC project has done anything (like introducing an escape as discussed in the links above) to address this yet. A quick look at the code and documentation suggests they didn't, but I didn't dig too deep.

**Addendum**: As shown in [the answer by bobmarksie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35359516/466862), current versions of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver now support escaping the question mark by doubling it (ie: use `??` instead of `?`).

Comment: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/35359516/1692179) - escaping is available and described (as of feb 2016) in the PosgreSQL documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue a couple of days ago and after some investigation I found this.

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/statement.html

> *In JDBC, the question mark (`?`) is the placeholder for the positional parameters of a PreparedStatement. There are, however, a number of PostgreSQL operators that contain a question mark. To keep such question marks in a SQL statement from being interpreted as positional parameters, use two question marks (`??`) as escape sequence. You can also use this escape sequence in a Statement, but that is not required. Specifically only in a Statement a single (`?`) can be used as an operator.*

Using 2 question marks seemed to work well for me - I was using the following driver (illustrated using maven dependency) ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
```

... and MyBatis for creating the SQL queries and it seemed to work well.  Seemed easier / cleaner than creating an PostgreSQL operator.

SQL went from e.g.

```
select * from user_docs where userTags ?| array['sport','property']
```

... to ...

```
select * from user_docs where userTags ??| array['sport','property']
```

Hopefully this works with your scenario!

Answer (score 0):

As bob said just use `??` instead of `?`

```
SQL(s"SELECT id FROM program WHERE document -> 'dept' ?? {dept}")
.on('dept -> "CS")
```