# Inserting data to a PostgreSQL jsonb column via Scala Anorm (in Play Framework)

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, anorm

The `data` column of PostgreSQL table `my_table` is of format `jsonb`. I would like to insert a Scala `JsObject` (or `JsValue`), but don't know how to do it!

The following code does not compile, because the `on` function expects `json` to be a `String`:

```
  def add(json: JsObject): Option[Long] = {
    DB.withConnection {
      implicit c =>

        val query = """
             insert into my_table(data)
        values({data});"""

        SQL(query).on(
          "data" -> json
        ).executeInsert()
    }
  }
```

What is the solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL jsonb, \`?\` and JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573778/postgresql-jsonb-and-jdbc)

Comment: A specific parameter conversion can be plugged to prepare part of SQL statement and pass JSON values.

Comment: @applicius It's not a duplicate of [PostgreSQL jsonb, '?' and JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573778/postgresql-jsonb-and-jdbc). My question is about an `insert` statement.

Comment: @Blackbird do you solve this problem ?

Comment: @mgosk No I didn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Borrowing from @KJay_wer, we can use `::jsonb` tag with Scala Anorm (Play Framework) too, and convert your `JsObject` (or other `JsValue`) into `String`:

```scala
def add(json: JsObject): Option[Long] = {
    DB.withConnection {
      implicit c =>

        val query = """
             insert into my_table (data)
             values ({data}::jsonb);
             """.stripMargin

        SQL(query).on(
          "data" -> json.toString
        ).executeInsert()
    }
  }
```

Comment: just tested it with `::json`

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, thanks! But it's been so long ago, I unfortunately cannot verify it. I've upvoted it though :)

Comment: I tested `::json` with all the tags on the question and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Is it `::json`, or `::jsonb` as in your code example?

Comment: In the code example above I put `::jsonb` to match the original question; I used `::json` on my use case, which was slightly different. I assume the solution works for your original case too.

Answer (score 3):

Use **::jsonb** tag at the end of a value. eg.

```
//my scala variables

val jsonDescription: String = "{\"name\":\"ksulr\"}"
val age = 15

//my insert statement
val sql = "INSERT into person(json_description,age) VALUES(?::jsonb,?)"

//prepared statement
val statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql)

//insert values into the sql statement
statement.setString(1,jsonDescription)
statement.setInt(2,age)

statement.executeUpdate()
```

This will work. It worked for me. Thats how I inserted into a `postgres db` column of type `jsonb`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It probably works, but it's not using Anorm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToStatement converter object:

```
def add(json: JsObject): Option[Long] = {
   DB.withConnection { implicit c =>       
      val query = """insert into my_table(data) values(${data});"""
      SQL(query).executeInsert()
   }
}

implicit object jsObjectStatement extends ToStatement[JsObject] {
    override def set(s: PreparedStatement, index: Int, v: JsObject): Unit = {
      val jsonObject = new PGobject()
      jsonObject.setType("json")
      jsonObject.setValue(Json.stringify(v))
      s.setObject(index, jsonObject)
    }
  }
```