# On laravel using builder query whereRaw ?&

Tags: postgresql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have problem using query whereraw on laravel 5.5 postgresql, for this case i want to select data by colors. [Data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSTKu.png)
Source postgresql [documentation postgres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcMVL.png). I'm success to try on execute sql like this [success example execute query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSPgz.png). But fail using laravel [example source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbC47.png). [Error on laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHt0H.png)

Comment: You won't get much help by posting links to some pics... Better make an effort and post text / code (copy&paste it's not that hard to do).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your statement contains a question mark. When using the whereRaw method, the question mark is an expected parameter, which aren't providing in your call.

However it seems that there isn't a real solution for this issue. I suggest you take a look at [Question mark operator in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29944704/question-mark-operator-in-query), it handles about a similar issue.