# How to use postgres jsonb operator '?' in laravel 5

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, jsonb

I'm trying to run a query with jsonb `?` operator  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html. In database console its ok, but i can't prepare it in laravel. Query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM game_user WHERE roles ? 'TRAINER'
```

I try `DB::raw()`, `DB::statement()` etc, but every time i have error:

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  Syntax error (near: "$1")
>   LINE 1: SELECT id FROM game_user WHERE roles $1 'TRAINER'
>                                                ^ (SQL: SELECT id FROM game_user WHERE roles ? 'TRAINER')

How i must do query without prepearing for arguments - `?` to `$1`

Comment: Show us **how** you used `DB::raw`.

Comment: I'm trying this:
$trainers = DB::table('game_user')
            ->select('*')
            ->whereRaw("roles ? '$trainerRole' AND game_id = $gameId")
            ->get()->all();
and this:
$trainers = DB::table(DB::raw("SELECT id FROM game_user WHERE roles ? '$trainerRoleName' AND game_id = $gameId"));
and this

Comment: and:
$trainers = DB::table('game_user')
            ->select('*')
            ->whereRaw(DB::raw(" roles ? '$trainerRole' AND game_id = $gameId"))->get()->all();

Comment: This link may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573778/postgresql-jsonb-and-jdbc/27580137#27580137

Comment: As well as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311939/how-to-prevent-pdo-from-interpreting-a-question-mark-as-a-placeholder

Comment: Thank you! Last link is perfect solution.