# MySQL insert parameter inside REGEXP

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement

I use MySQL C Connector. My prepared statement looks like this:

```
"SELECT x FROM y WHERE z REGEXP '^BLA?$'"
```

The problem is that ? character is treated like part of REGEXP, when I need to insert parameter there later. How can I make ? to be treated like placeholder for data?

Comment: Just a guess but maybe `REGEXP CONCAT('^BLA', ?, '$')`?

Comment: What type of input are you accepting into the `?` parameter? Is it strictly range-limited and validated? There may be better solutions than concatenating it into the regexp.

Comment: @Uueerdo Not just a guess - that is a working solution.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski wasn't sure; I almost never need to use regexp in MySQL, so that aspect is mostly "academic" for me.

Comment: @Uueerdo You ought to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`REGEXP CONCAT('^BLA', ?, '$')` this should work. However, if you need that parameter AND a '?', like this `CONCAT('^BLAH', ?, '?$')`, I am not sure if that latter ? will need escaped, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26516204/how-do-i-escape-a-literal-question-mark-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement) it should be fine without escaping it.

Comment: as a note, this is applicable for pretty much ANY situation where you need to embed a placeholder some other string. `'?'` is a question mark to mysql, so you need to "extract" the `?` from the string, which is where concat() comes in handy.