# Slick plain SQL escape PostgreSQL json function

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to escape the `?|` operator in this query:

```
val data = sql"""
  SELECT ......
  FROM .......
  WHERE table.column ?| array['23', '12']
""".as[Int].head

db.run(data)
```

however the `?|` operator gets translated as `$1|` in the query (checked in the DB query log) and it obviously generates the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1" at character 735
```

I've tried with `#?|` and `$?|` without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` is a placeholder for a parameter in JDBC (that's the level after Slick). You can escape `?` [specifically for PostgreSQL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/statement.html) as `??|`.  There's useful discussion of this in [SO 14779896 - Does the JDBC spec prevent '?' from being used as an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779896/does-the-jdbc-spec-prevent-from-being-used-as-an-operator-outside-of-quotes/14786469).

An alternative to this convention would be to use non-symbolic alternatives: `jsonb_exists_any`. E.g.,

```
WHERE jsonb_exists_any(table.column, array['23', '12'])
```

Comment: I'me very sorry, I've made so many changes that I've copied the last try instead of the original one, I've updated the question

Comment: I found that I need to use `??` *not* `??|`