# Postgres driver replaces ? with $1

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

```
UPDATE datasource set metadata = (metadata::jsonb -'statisticsCalculation') 
WHERE metadata ? 'statisticsCalculation';
```

statement stored in sqlfile, when applying changes with liquibase postgresql driver replaces ? with $1.

```
<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
<artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
<version>42.2.5</version>
```

Notice: works properly with driver version 9.4.x

Comment: Maybe escaping it to `??` works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30517450/14955