# Does MyBatis support PostgreSQL support full range of JSONB operators (?, @>, etc.)

Tags: postgresql, mybatis, jsonb

Related to

- [How do I use PostgreSQL JSON(B) operators containing a question mark "?" via JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370972/how-do-i-use-postgresql-jsonb-operators-containing-a-question-mark-via-jdb#)
- [Does the JDBC spec prevent '?' from being used as an operator (outside of quotes)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779896/does-the-jdbc-spec-prevent-from-being-used-as-an-operator-outside-of-quotes/30517450#30517450)

List of Operators --> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html

Changing my queries in an attempt to escape didn't do the trick.  Using ?? vs ? and `<CDATA`.. etc.

Comment: `??` worked fine (tested with PostgreSQL 11.4 and pgjdbc 42.2.10). Please post 1) what you tried and 2) how it failed exactly.

Comment: what version of mybatis are you using?  we're on 3.5.2 and pgjdbc 42.2.6

Comment: I used MyBatis 3.5.4 + pgjdbc 42.2.10, but 3.5.2 + 42.2.6 worked as well. Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/so-60142943/so-60142943) that I used to verify.