# Any way to disable parameters or execute SQL statements directly in JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, hstore

I am trying to ues JDBC PreparedStatement to execute a SQL statement which has a question mark `?` as operator. (It's the [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) `?|` operator)

It throws an exception tells me that I have not specified the parameter `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No value specified for parameter 1.`. Which it should be the operator. Is there any way to by pass the parameter check and  execute the statement directly?

I have seen database feature in IntelliJ can directly execute SQL with JDBC driver, I think there should be a way

There is an question ([Escaping hstore contains operators in a JDBC Prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940401/escaping-hstore-contains-operators-in-a-jdbc-prepared-statement)) about this issue, but I really need this operator to make index working on large data sets.

Thank you

Comment: Get it working with `createStatement().executeQuery`, still wondering how to get it working with preparedStatement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SQL function inlining. A simple SQL function will get rewritten (almost always).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hstore_contains(hstore, text[]) RETURNS boolean AS $$
    SELECT $1 ?| $2;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

So the two queries below will get identical query plan and will both take advantage of indexes:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE hstore_contains(col1,array['a','b']);

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col1 ?| array['a','b'];
```

Comment: Thank you. When and where should I execute this create function statement? Before every query of only once? Is it persistent？

Comment: @Shisoft Only once (although it won't fail if run it more than once). If you don't want to create a permanent function you can also take a look at temporary solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9981540/2115135